# Adding background music that fades out with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, git-bash

I have a piece of video that is 30fps and simply want to add overlay faint background music starting at 10 seconds.  Then I want it to fade out during the last 15 seconds.  I can't find any good examples of this other than weird hacks.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i outro.mp3 -t 10 \
  -filter_complex "[a0][1:a]acrossfade=d=15[a];weight1:0.5" \
  -map '[v]' -map '[a]' out.mp4
```

I get bad arguments in the filter_complex.  Somethings off right there. in terms of the duration.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i outro.mp3 \
  -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0,asplit[0a][0acf];[1:a]adelay=10s|10s[1a];\
                   [0a][1a]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,volume=2,afifo[outro];\
                   [0acf]atrim=0:16,afifo[0acf];[outro][0acf]acrossfade=d=15[outro];\
                   [0:a][outro]amix=duration=first:weights='2 1'[a]" \
  -map 0:v -c:v copy -map '[a]' out.mp4`

The main audio is muted and then cloned to two copies. It is then mixed with the delayed music so that the music duration matches the main audio. It is then crossfaded with the other copy of the muted main audio. This result is then mixed with the original main audio.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, I get an error I didn't get before which prevents it from running.:

`[Parsed_volume_0 @ 0000021d3c53afc0] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_volume_0' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_split_1' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000021d3c53d1c0] Cannot create the link volume:0 -> split:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`

Comment: I get this error now:

`[Parsed_amix_7 @ 000002369c81dec0] Option 'weight' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002369c7fc400] Error initializing filter 'amix' with args 'duration=first:weight=2 1'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found`

Does amix need inputs like the line above it?  I looked at documenation and I attempted amix=2:duration.. and it did not work either.

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg to 4.0 or later.

Comment: i am at ffmpeg 4.2

Comment: Ok, the options is weights, not weight

Comment: alright that worked, but it is yelling at me for the mapping of [v], since it is not used above.  I see you stripped the audio from [0] since it is necessary to merge it back in for the fade, but since there is no "v" it is throwing a fit.

`Output with label 'v' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.`

Comment: I copied that from your Q without checking. Changed.

Comment: I'll have to debug that when I have time.

Comment: Ok, modified with workaround till the bug is identified

Comment: I want to add background music for last 5 second in a mp4 video.how ? or fade in last 5 seconds. first time fade out then fade in for last 5 seconds.Please help.